# Interaction between objects

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have a class Music like this

```
class Music{
  private:
    string song[20];
    string album[20];
    string artistName[20];
    string genre[20];
    static int i;
    int j;
    int duration[20];
  public:
    Music(string musicName,string artist,string genre,string albumname,int duration);
    void  addMusic(string musicName,string artist,string genre,string albumname,int duration);
    bool browseMusic(string musicName);
    void getParticularSongDetail(string musicName);
    void totalNumberOfSongs();

};
```

and a person class like this

```
class Person{

  public:
    Person(string,string,string);
    string getFirstName();
    string getMiddleName();
    string getLastName();
    int getId();
  private:
    //some variables
}
```

how can I add 20 songs to Music class that belongs to a particular person?

Comment: What's the relation between Person and Music?

Comment: Generally, you would have a `Music` object in `Person` or have a separate structure (like a map) to associate them.

Comment: Person has 20 songs which he browses and adds new songs

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on how you wish to design your program.

The following are some possible solutions for you:

1. The Person could have an array of Music objects.
2. The Music class could have a keep track of the Peron's id it belongs to.
3. The Music classes may be something you won't want to repeat between users, so you might make a 3rd class which helps make the associations. (e.g. Multiple people might own the same Tool album CD/mp3, so another class could help you make the associations, or you might have an array in your Music class to keep track of multiple Persons... Normally a "list" would be a better datatype than an array, however from your code examples I stuck to arrays to keep the response simple).